# Can't change the brightness with nomodeset

Tags: brightness, nomodeset

If I try and boot without nomodeset I go to a black screen. On this I can adjust my brightness using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd>/<kbd>-></kbd> but I can't actually do anything.

I can boot with nomodeset but then I cannot change brightness. I have tried boot options like `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` which have no effect.

I've seen some recommendations to edit  `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, but my `/sys/class/backlight` directory is empty.

I'm guessing there's a problem with my video drivers (I have Intel HD 4000)?

The output of lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA is as follows

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor
> Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
>
> Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0799]
>
> 00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family>USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
>
> Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0799]
>
> Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
>
> 00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)

Comment: From where did you change the options `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`? From `/etc/default/grub`? It should work..

Comment: Could you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA`?

Comment: Saurav: I edited /etc/default/grub, in particular the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line reads quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor.

Comment: @Adrian did you get the solution for this? I have MSI GE62 facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's like a brute force method it worked for me. Initially, when my Ubuntu was stuck at the purple screen:

1. I restarted the system.
2. Pressed <kbd>E</kbd> key and added `nomodeset` as: `ro quiet splash &vt_handoff nomodeset`.
3. Pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> and once the system restarts , open terminal.
4. Write `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub/` in the terminal.
5. Add `nomodeset` like this, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
6. Save the file and write `sudo update-grub`.

Now the main part:

7. Go to applications and open software and update.
8. Click additional drivers and choose the recommended one and NOT X.Org xserver.
9. Once Done with this, restart the system.
10. But this time again press <kbd>E</kbd> on grub menu and (remove) `nomodeset` and press <kbd>F10</kbd>.
11. The system will start normally.
12. Once started, open the grub file again as in step 4, but this time remove `nomodeset` and save the file.
13. Write `sudo update-grub` and restart the system.

Congratulations! Now your system will work perfectly with normal boot, without `nomodeset` and you would be able to inc/dec the screen brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wrote scripts to compensate for the loss of backlight control with nomodeset. If this is still a thing you could try out the intelBrightness file from https://github.com/vjay82/Linux-i915-Backlight-Control

Comment: Please include the essential part of the solution